# How we get 10 record from Api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have call an api which has 25 record. How we call this api First time I am getting only ten record.And then after 10. and then Remaining.

I am done by using database.Call web service and insert response in database and get 10 record. But our boss say not using this approach, Get 10 record from web service. How can I use this?. Please help

Comment: Ask your parent, sibling whether or not they understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @ElTomato your comment is as useless as the incomprehensible question by OP. nainsigupta, please edit your question to add more relevant details. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and other help topics thoroughly before posting a question if you really want good quality answers. If not, most of the questions in the format you've posted above will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

in here you can do this in two ways

> Initially u get all records from your web service and load the 10, 10 data on your table, this is one time call the web service.

*Step-1*

```
@interface searchResultsViewController
{
int loadMoreItems;
}
```

*Step-2*

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
loadMoreItems=11;
[self callyourwebservice];
}
```

*step-3*

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if ([yourarray count]<=loadMoreItems) {
        return [yourarray count];
    }
    else {
        // load load extra items
        return loadMoreItems;
    }
 }
```

*step-4*

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

 ........

 if (indexPath.row+1<loadMoreItems)
  {
 cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;
    }
            else
            {
 cell.textLabel.text = @"Load more results...!";
            }
 }
```

*step-5*

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (indexPath.row+1<loadMoreItems) {
   // do your stuff here
 }
    else {
        loadMoreItems=loadMoreItems+10;
        [self.tblvie reloadData];
    }
 }
```

> you can set the page call (set some identification page for how many data are received), initially call first web service using Page one key ==0 and load the data in table when last row u meet in table call another web service like  Page one key ==1 , etc...

example

*step-1*

```
 @interface HomeViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
 int pagecount;
 }
```

*Step-2*

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 pagecount =1;
[self callyourwebservice];
}
```

*step-3*

```
   -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  if(indexPath.row == yourarray.count - 1)
{
    NSLog(@"lasrt row called");

    [self launchReload];

}
}

-(void) launchReload
{
pagecount=pagecount+1;
// do something
[yourtableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: you need the example for both I add here

Comment: second option in backend side you need to change the call type of web service, in first choice no need of this

Comment: check the updated answer